Script that interacts with router's web configuration
I suppose powershell have all the commands, but I'm not sure exactly how to do it.
I need the script to open router's web configuration, log in, go into firewall tab, read from test.txt and parse lines to create outbound rules. And every time I would launch the script, it needs to check if new lines were added to the test.txt, if true, then create new rules in firewall.
Hope this is easy to achieve.
Right now didn't try anything.

Yes it is possible.  What is model of router?  I would first try manually using Putty and then convert to PS.

Without knowing more about what kind of router you are dealing with, generally the easiest way to run a script of any kind against a router is to do it via SSH (this is what jdweng was referring to with PuTTY). A lot of the store-bought routers these days have some form of DD-WRT. They have the ability to allow SSH for remote management. From there, depending on what you are trying to change, you locate the file that stores its configuration and edit it. Doesn't necessarily have to be PowerShell, but PowerShell could likely do it. The exact steps would require a lot more information from your end. Is the process easy? It is if you are an experienced IT professional, otherwise I do not recommend you attempt this as you could potentially lock yourself out of the router.

Thanks for the reply, I already tried SSH, but because I'm using cheap TP-Link, all SSH ports on their routers are locked to proprietary Tether app only. There is a possibilty to reverse engineer firmware to get the key, but I won't even try. I'm going to try to do it through iwr

If the rules you are creating are to block ads or some other URLs, I might suggest using Pi-Hole. Its easy to add Ad block lists and you can add custom URLs to be blacklisted (or whitelisted). It does require a VM or another computer to install on. Once configured you point your router and other clients DNS to the IP of it.
